# My element is constantly displaying even before the user has clicked on it to trigger the function (on click function)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My Javascript drop down navigation function is now working on mobile which is great however now on my "About Page" and "Index page" the drop down wording (which is only meant to display once the user has clicked) is constantly showing (see video attached). I do not understand why this is as on other pages the drop down does not show before click...

I have attached a video. Is someone able to look at my repo and tell me if they can see an issue? VIDEO: https://www.loom.com/share/0f829fc9d6664648802998f5cf4bcead

REPO TO CLONE IF NEEDED: git@github.com:Angela-Inniss/CB.git

Here is the website on Heroku: https://cb-carpet-cleaning-services.herokuapp.com/ (in progress).

I have tried to display none the menu on mobile, but this hides the whole menu.

My js on click function

```
const dropDown = document.getElementById("nav-bar-grey"); 
const navBarOpen = document.getElementById("new-drop-down-js"); 
dropDown.onclick = showNav 
const closeButton = document.getElementById("closebtn");
closeButton.onclick = closeNav


function showNav (event) {
    navBarOpen.classList.toggle("nav-open");
  }

  function closeNav (event) {
    navBarOpen.classList.toggle("nav-close");
  }
```

about page mobile.html.erb

```
<!--//mobile -->

<div class="background-about-mobile">
  <div class="white-bg-about">

    <h3>About.</h3>
    <div class="dash"> - </div>
    <h6>Who are we?</h6>

    <p class="about-text-mobile">We are a professional Carpet cleaning company that operates in the Leicestershire Region. Specialising in Carpet, Upholstery, hard floors, blinds and curtain cleaning fully insured, DBS Checked with 12 years plus experience.</p>
    <div class="dash"> - </div>
    <h6>What Services do we provide?</h6>

   <ul>
     <li>- Carpet cleaning</li>
     <li>- Rug cleaning</li>
     <li>- Stain removal</li>
     <li>- Amtico and Karndean maintenance</li>
     <li>- Hard Floor Maintence</li>
     <li>- Curtains and blinds cleaning.</li>
    </ul>


  </div>
```

I expect the drop down menu not appear before it has been clicked on, on mobile.

Comment: First of all can you replace "const" keyword with "var" or "let" keyword ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to update your javascript code with

Setting height:0px is only reducing the height of your div element that's why all the child nodes are visible you can achieve it by adding below css code

```
 .nav-close a{
   display : none;
 }
```

or

```
 #new-drop-down-js{
  display : none;  // set the default value as none
}

.nav-open{
  display :block !important;
}

.nav-close{
 display : none ;
}
```